# Android Dependency Injection/Service Locator

Tags: android

Необходимо переписать старое приложение на новый стек и архитектуру. 
В качестве стека буду использовать Kotlin + MVVM (LiveData) (без Databinding, так как мне он не нравится из-за сложности отладки).

Так как приложение содержит более 100 экранов, то задумался о внедрении зависимостей, так как самому вручную не очень то и охота.

Последний раз когда я использовал Dagger 2, я слышал по сути о двух библиотеках: собственно Dagger2 и Toothpick. Выбрал Dagger2 за более высокой производительности

Сейчас я вижу появился Kodein и Koin.

Посоветуйте какой лучше использовать в продакшене на такой размер приложения и почему. (Так же желаю, чтобы вес не существенно прибавился).

Буду рад любым советам

Answer (score 2):

Dagger - это классика. Его поддерживает Google. Он существует давно со всеми вытекающими:

- скорость
- возможности
- поддержка

Koin написан на Kotlin и он больше подходит для проектов на Kotlin (хотя поддержка Java есть).

- не особо уступает по скорости даггеру.
- намного меньше шаблонного кода
- понятнее и ниже порог вхождения.

С остальными я не знаком лично. Но я видел серьезные проекты где используются эти библиотеки.

Вот неплохая [статья](https://medium.com/@elye.project/dagger-2-and-koin-comparison-4223dae9725d) где сравнивают Dagger и Koin

Comment: а не скинете ссылки на серьезный проект, где используется Koin?

Comment: Если вы хотите ссылки на код, то нет. Это проекты не опен сорс. Один из таких это https://www.zemingo.com/ там работает мой знакомый. Еще слышал хорошие отзывы от ребят на митапах, но там не вспомню кто где работает.

Comment: @SergeuBuvaka я имел ввиду, пример кода, хотя бы на десяток экранов, использующих несколько репозиториев.(MVVM)

А то я нахожу только example - app, в котором только 1 - 2 экрана, толку то для них DI вообще использовать.

Comment: Ну вам надо шерстить весь Гит и искать опен сорс какой-то. Потому-что проект на десяток экранов редко пишут просто так чтоб показать другим

Comment: https://github.com/industradamus/TheMovie Это мой некогда учебный проект. Тут 2 экрана и пару вспомогательных